# Make gantt chart a figure

Tags: table-of-contents, pgfgantt, gantt

I would like my Gantt chart to appear in my **list of figures**. Is there an easy way of 'casting' the Gantt chart to a figure format that would then automatically include it in the list of figures?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you already try to place it insode of a `figure` environment while also adding a `\caption`there?

Comment: Yes, I did this; it messes up my page layout. My Gantt chart is on a landscape page, and as soon as I place it in the figure environment, it bumps it to the next page and causes it to be placed on a portrait page.

Comment: probably, `sidewaysfigure` from the `rotating` package could be of help in this situation?

Comment: Thanks. The 'sidewaysfigure' did the trick @leandriis

Comment: You can also use `\captionof{figure}{...}` (caption package), although it might get out of order relative to the floats.  (The list of figures is really a list of captions; no caption, no en\try.)